# Prove equation involving partial derivative analytically with Coq

Tags: coq

I want to prove following lemma.

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.

Lemma request_id {A}(a b:t R A): request a b = b.
Proof.
induction A.
refine (match b with nil => _ end) => //.
rewrite /request.
Abort.
```

The following processing is performed on all elements of a. I want to prove that it will be same as b when all processing is finished. a and b are vectors. i and k are indices. `∇a_i` represents differentiation on a_i. `∑` represents sumation.

```
a_i - ∇a_i(∑(1/2)(a_k - b_k)^2)
           k
```

How do you prove this with Coq?

```
Require Import Psatz.

Definition kLess : forall (k P:nat), (P - k) < (S P).
intros. lia.
Defined.

Theorem arith_basic : forall (k P:nat), lt k P -> P = Nat.add k (S (P - (k + 1))).
  intros. lia.
Defined.

Definition k1Less : forall (k P:nat), ((S P)-((P-k)+1)) < (S P).
intros. lia.
Defined.

Definition kLess2 : forall (k P:nat), (P - k) <= (S P).
intros. lia.
Defined.

Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Require Import Coquelicot.Coquelicot.
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.
Open Scope R_scope.
Open Scope vector_scope.

Notation "A ::: B" := (Vector.cons _ A _ B)(at level 60, right associativity).
Notation "[ r1 , .. , r2 ]" := (@cons R r1 _ .. ( @cons R r2 _ (@nil R) ) .. ).

Fixpoint lastk k n : t R n -> (lt k n) -> t R k :=
  match n with
    |0%nat => fun _ (H : lt k 0) => False_rect _ (@Lt.lt_n_O k H)
    |S n => match k with
              |S m => fun v H => shiftin (Vector.last v) (lastk m n (shiftout v) (@le_S_n _ _ H))
              |0%nat => fun _ H => nil R
            end
  end.

Definition EucSum {A}(e:t R A) :R:= Vector.fold_right Rplus e 0.
Definition QE (r1 r2:R):R:= (1 / 2)*(r1 - r2)^2.
Definition QuadraticError {n : nat} (v1 v2: t R n) :t R n:= Vector.map2 QE v1 v2.

Definition deriveA {A}(k:nat)(a b:t R (S A)):R.
pose H := kLess k A.
apply arith_basic in H.
rewrite H in b.
pose lk := lastk ((S A)-((A-k)+1)) (S A) a (k1Less k A).
pose fk := take (A-k) (kLess2 k A) a.
pose ak := nth_order a (kLess k A).
exact ( Derive (fun AK => EucSum (QuadraticError (append fk (AK ::: lk)) b )) ak ).
Defined.

Fixpoint updateRnA {A} (k:nat)(a b:t R (S A)):t R (S k):=
 match k in nat return t R (S k) with
   |S k' => (nth_order a (kLess k A)) - (deriveA k a b) ::: updateRnA k' a b
   |0%nat => [(Vector.last a) - (deriveA k a b)]
   end.

Definition request {A} :t R A -> t R A -> t R A.
 refine (match A with
           | 0%nat => fun _ _ => nil R
           | S A' => _
           end).
 intros a b.
 exact (updateRnA A' a b).
Defined.
```